# How can I make a .net standard fully compatible with legacy projects?

Tags: .net-standard

I'm trying to develop a .NET 7.0 Console application  `CustomizedTelegramBot` that needs to reference a .NET 4.7 Framework library `DataBase`.

I have added a .NET Standard 2.0 project `DataBaseWrapper` to my solution that references `DataBase` and `CustomizedTelegramBot` references `DataBaseWrapper`.

It seems to work fine, but as soon as the `DataBase` library calls a referenced dll, I get a `FileNotFound` error:

```
Polling failed with exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Impossibile trovare il file specificato.
      File name: 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
         at System.Data.DB.DataBase.Execute(Boolean ShowError, CallType Type, String SQLString, Object[] Args)
         at System.Data.DB.DataBase.Execute(String SQLString, Object[] Args) in ****\Projects\Varie per VS\DataBase\Database.vb:line 384
         at CustomizedTelegramBot.Articolo..ctor(BotConfiguration config, String codice) in ****\Projects\Telegram.Bot.Examples-master\DataBaseWrapper\Articolo.cs:line 31
         at Telegram.Bot.Services.UpdateHandler.BotOnMessageReceived(Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in ****\Projects\Telegram.Bot.Examples-master\CustomizedTelegramBot\Services\UpdateHandler.cs:line 58
         [...]
```

`System.Data.SqlClient` is one of the .NET Framework classes that I have to use.

Other .NET Framework classes are database specifics and I could not find them in `.nuget` packages.

Comment: "I'm trying to develop a .net core 7.0 Console application witch needs to implement a .net 4.7 framework library. I tried to add to my solution a .net standard 2.0 project to references to that library and my .net core project references to that intermediate library."
This is unclear. What are you implementing, and what are you referencing?

Comment: I created a solution with three projects. The main one (a Telegram Bot App Console, which must be a .net core 7.0 application). The second one (an old .net framework 4.7 dll library referencing 3rd party libraries). To make the first one uses the second, I tried to create a third project (.net standard 2.0). So the third project refers to the second and the first refers to the third.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your approach will work.
My suggestion is to create a .NET Standard version of 'Database', either by copying the code into a new project, or by using multitargeting (more difficult).

Comment: I tried to create a new project (Database) and copy into it all I had to copy. The compile returns no errors, but during the runtime I have this exception: Polling failed with exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'DataBase.DataBase' from assembly 'DataBase, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be3d48c30bff564f'

Comment: Ok, I don't know why, but I resolved. I cleaned Database project from any .net framework object and create a .Net 7.0 project. I had the same error. I tought the error was in something of strange inside the CustomizedTelegramBot. I created a new CustomizedTelegramBot project with the same content. Now it runs well, also if it is referenced to the .NET standard version

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this package **"System.Data.DataSetExtensions"**

Try installing this package and then try